# Set default content_type for Sinatra

Tags: json, ruby, rest, sinatra, content-type

In Sinatra is it possible to make `content_type 'application/json'` the default? Because I'm building a REST API.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a JSON API the most recommendable way to set a default `Content-Type` for all your responses is to add the following in your Sinatra class:

```
set :default_content_type, :json
```

It will include a `Content-Type: application/json` header in all your responses.

Comment: Or even `set :default_content_type, :json`

Answer (score 78):

Sure, add `content_type` to the `before` callback:

```
class MyApp < Sinatra::Base

  before do
    content_type 'application/json'
  end

  ...

end
```

[Sinatra 1.1](http://ididitmyway.heroku.com/past/2010/11/14/sinatra_11_released/) introduces pattern-matching before filters:

```
before '/admin/*' do
  check_logged_in
end
```

Comment: Thanks! How do I create a context so that the before filter is only applied to a specific group of routes and not all?

Comment: @MattDiPasquale This should do the trick: http://blog.alastairdawson.com/2010/07/27/a-sinatra-before-only-filter/

Comment: @MattDePasqaule you can also override the content type within individual routes.

Comment: sinatra 1.1 supports pattern before filter, so the patch is not necessary.

Comment: @Konstantin thanks for the heads up, much better than my suggestion.

Comment: @Adam Lassek, thanks for all your help! @Konstantin, pretty sweet. Thanks! Oh yeah, I see [before filters with pattern matching](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Filters) on the README now. I must've missed that. Thanks.